# Hibernate one-to-many mapping with foreign key being part of composite primary key

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, orm

I'm trying to create a Hibernate mapping for the following relation:

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (
    id   UUID PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE user_roles (
    user_id UUID NOT NULL,
    role    TEXT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT pk_user_roles UNIQUE(user_id, role),
    CONSTRAINT fk_user_roles_users FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
);
```

I'd also like User entity to be able to list their assigned roles. I came up with the following:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    @Column(name="id")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    @BatchSize(size=10)
    private Set<UserRole> roles = new HashSet<>();

    // ...
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="user_roles")
@IdClass(UserRoleId.class)
public class UserRole {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private UUID userId;  // I don't need this field here, had to add it because Hibernate requires it

    @Id
    @Column(name="role", nullable = false)
    private String role;

    // ...
}
```

```java
public class UserRoleId implements Serializable {
    private UUID userId;

    private String role;

    // ...
}
```

This seems to be working, but when I try to add new role to existing User entity and than persist this entity than I get the following:

```
org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement [No value specified for parameter 3.] [insert into user_roles (user_id,role,user_id) values (?,?,?)]
```

Does anyone has any idea how to achieve exactly what I want? I've tried adding artificial auto-incrementing key to UserRole and making it a primary key. It worked, but it looked like an ugly workaround.

BTW: I'm using Hibernate 6.x that comes with the Quarkus framework.

Comment: You need to map the User inside the UserRole as a ManyToOne because UserRole is actually a child entity of User, and add mapped by to @OneToMany: `@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "user")`

Comment: When I modify mappings like this I get `ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement [ERROR: null value in column "user_id" of relation "user_roles" violates not-null constraint` when trying to persist new UserRole entity.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I figured it out. First mapping needs to be changed like that

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    @Column(name="id")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @BatchSize(size=10)
    private List<UserRole> roles = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="user_roles")
@IdClass(UserRoleId.class)
public class UserRole {
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;

    @Id
    @Column(name="role", nullable = false)
    private String role;
}
```

But the issue itself was in the way entities were persisted

```java
var role = new UserRole();
role.setUser(user);  // <-- this line was missing
role.setRole(roleName);
user.getRoles().add(role);

entityManager.merge(user);
```